# Google reducing indexed page count

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Our website has more than 6,000,000 pages, all of them were generated using my software (those were keyword replaced pages), but all of them are actual pages.

Google indexed most of those pages and we are happy, but recently, the past two weeks, Google reducing the indexed page count, now its about 2,000,000.

Is there any Google new update in that last couple of weeks is there any work around for this to get our pages index?

Update

No page error. no server down, DNS is fine, wat else pretty much everything is fine. apart from qualify of content as some is duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. This content is low quality content. You took existing content, changed the words, and republished it. This is *exactly* what Google doesn't want. Expect the trend of pages being removed from Google's index to continue and don't be surprised if the site these pages are on suddenly disappears from Google's index in one fell swoop.

Comment: I know its low quality content, but say we provide a service in leeds and liverpool so our pages will be A services in leeds and  A service in liverpool, so when some one look for a service in liverpool it should be fine, but google robots dont like it i know.

Comment: If you know Google doesn't like this kind of content, why are you surprised they are taking action against it?

Comment: Because it was alright for more than a year and it was happening just in last couple of weeks so just checking if there is an update Google Indexing.

Comment: It wasn't alright for a year. Google just didn't catch you yet. There was no major change made by Google. They are constantly updating their algorithm to filter out this kind of content.

Comment: As John is touching on, your tactics were just detected. And early on, I did similar things...Unfortunately, spammy stuff works for a while; it works until you get caught or an algo update comes along. If you want to rank for different locations I recommend looking into accurate use of structured data (e.g. schema.org) to ensure that search engines clearly understand the areas your business serves (indexing)...combined with legitimate off-page SEO methods (ranking).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you used a keyword spinner software. NEVER DO THIS! It is a search no no. What floors me is that these packages still exist. Mostly they are only useful on smaller less sophisticated localized search engines such as some of the Russian search engines. Other than that, spinning never really worked well or for very long.

Here is a tip. Other than SEO performance analysis software, do not buy a software package or service the promises to boost your rank and/or search engine performance. Most if not all are junk. Gaming the system is a fools errand.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't **ever** *"work around"* some SEO problem!
Never go for the cheap solution.

This makes me wonder if you have more of those 'work arounds', if so, then that's your problem. Focus on content, if you overoptimise for searchengines, you will rank down.

Apart from that, check your webmastertool and try to look around for tips on how to upgrade the SEO ranking. You might want to look into html-errors, or page speed, or caching. Never updating your site contributes to decreasing as well.